# Is it safe to release a chromecast android sender application that ports back to Android 2.2?

Tags: java, android, chromecast

I have an Android Sender Application for chromecast that ports back to Android 2.2. I am still using revision 16 of the Google Play Services SDK, which will not warn me about version 9. I know that Google Cast SDK is only supported back to android 2.3 but I have working code running on an android app that goes back to android 2.2 however since development Google Play services has been updated 2 times for the Cast SDK features.

Over the weekend, I have updated the revision to 17 now locking me to use Android 2.3. I have since overwrote the Google Play Services back to revision 16 to keep my build working and stable for Chromecast.

My question is if it is safe to release and Android Application with a minSDK = 8 where i restrict my chromecast implementation to >= 2.3?